# Finding all solutions to a non-linear equation system with MuPAD

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

My question is if there is a good way to use MuPAD functions in a Matlab script. The background is that I have a problem where I need to find all solutions to a set of non-linear equations. The previous solution was to use `solve` in Matlab, which works for some of my simulations (i.e., some of the sets of input `T`) but not always. So instead I'm using MuPAD in the following way:

```
function ut1 = testMupadSolver(T)
% # Input T should be a vector of 15 elements

mupadCommand = ['numeric::polysysroots({' eq1(T) ' = 0,' ...
    eq2(T) '= 0},[u, v])'];
allSolutions = evalin(symengine, mupadCommand);
ut1 = allSolutions;

end

function strEq = eq1(T)
sT = @(x) ['(' num2str(T(x)) ')'];

strEq = [ '-' sT(13) '*u^4 + (4*' sT(15) '-2*' sT(10) '-' sT(11) '*v)*u^3 + (3*' ...
    sT(13) '-3*' sT(6) '+v*(3*' sT(14) '-2*' sT(7) ')-' sT(8) '*v^2)*u^2 + (2*' ...
    sT(10) '-4*' sT(1) '+v*(2*' sT(11) '-3*' sT(2) ')+v^2*(2*' sT(12) ' - 2*' ...
    sT(3) ')-' sT(4) '*v^3)*u + v*(' sT(7) '+' sT(8) '*v+' sT(9) '*v^2)+' sT(6)];

end

function strEq = eq2(T)
sT = @(x) ['(' num2str(T(x)) ')'];
strEq = ['(' sT(14) '-' sT(13) '*v)*u^3 + u^2*' '(' sT(11) '+(2*' sT(12) '-2*' sT(10) ...
    ')*v-' sT(11) '*v^2) + u*(' sT(7) '+v*(2*' sT(8) '-3*' sT(6) ')+v^2*(3*' sT(9) ...
    '-2*' sT(7) ') - ' sT(8) '*v^3) + v*(2*' sT(3) '-4*' sT(1) '+v*(3*' sT(4) ...
    '-3*' sT(2) ')+v^2*(4*' sT(5) ' - 2*' sT(3) ')-' sT(4) '*v^3)+' sT(2)];

end
```

I have two queries:

1) In order to use MuPAD I need to rewrite my two equations for the equation-system as strings, as you can see above. Is there a better way to do this, preferably without the string step?

2) And regarding the format output; when

```
T = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1];
```

the output is:

```
testMupadSolver(T)

ans =

matrix([[u], [v]]) in {matrix([[4.4780323328249527319374854327354], [0.21316518769990291263811232040432]]), matrix([[- 0.31088044854742790561428736573347 - 0.67937835289645431373983117422178*i], [1.1103383836576028262792542770062 + 0.39498445715599777249947213893789*i]]), matrix([[- 0.31088044854742790561428736573347 + 0.67937835289645431373983117422178*i], [1.1103383836576028262792542770062 - 0.39498445715599777249947213893789*i]]), matrix([[0.47897094942962218512261248590261], [-1.26776233072168360314707025141]]), matrix([[-0.83524238515971910583152318717102], [-0.66607962429342496204955062300669]])} union solvelib::VectorImageSet(matrix([[0], [z]]), z, C_)
```

Can MuPAD give the solutions as a set of vectors or similarly? In order to use the answer above I need to sort out the solutions from that string-set of solutions. Is there a clever way to do this? My solution so far is to find the signs I know will be present in the solution, such as `'([['` and pick the numbers following, which is really ugly, and if the solution for some reason looks a little bit different than the cases I've covered it doesn't work.

## EDIT

When I'm using the solution suggested in the answer below by @horchler, I get the same solution as with my previous implementation. But for some cases (not all) it takes much longer time. Eg. for the T below the solution suggested below takes more than a minute whilst using evalin (my previous implementation) takes one second.

```
T = [2.4336 1.4309 0.5471 0.0934 9.5838 -0.1013 -0.2573 2.4830 ...
     36.5464 0.4898 -0.5383 61.5723 1.7637 36.0816 11.8262]
```

The new function:

```
function ut1 = testMupadSolver(T)
% # Input T should be a vector of 15 elements
allSolutions = feval(symengine,'numeric::polysysroots', ...
    [eq1(T),eq2(T)],'[u,v]');
end
function eq = eq1(T)
syms u v
eq = -T(13)*u^4 + (4*T(15) - 2*T(10) - T(11)*v)*u^3 + (3*T(13) - 3*T(6) ...
    + v*(3*T(14) -2*T(7)) - T(8)*v^2)*u^2 + (2*T(10) - 4*T(1) + v*(2*T(11) ...
    - 3*T(2)) + v^2*(2*T(12) - 2*T(3)) - T(4)*v^3)*u + v*(T(7) + T(8)*v ...
    + T(9)*v^2) + T(6);
end


function eq = eq2(T)
syms u v
eq = (T(14) - T(13)*v)*u^3 + u^2*(T(11) + (2*T(12) - 2*T(10))*v ...
    - T(11)*v^2) + u*(T(7) + v*(2*T(8) - 3*T(6) ) + v^2*(3*T(9) - 2*T(7)) ...
    - T(8)*v^3) + v*(2*T(3) - 4*T(1) + v*(3*T(4) - 3*T(2)) + v^2*(4*T(5) ...
    - 2*T(3)) - T(4)*v^3) + T(2);
end
```

Is there a good reason to why it takes so much longer time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Matlab communicates with MuPAD via string commands so ultimately there is no way of getting around the use of strings. And because it's the native format, if you're passing large amounts of data into MuPAD, the best approach will be to convert everything to strings fast and efficiently (`sprintf` is usually best). However, in your case, I think that you can use [`feval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/feval.html) instead of `evalin` which allows you to pass in regular Matlab datatypes (under the hood `sym/feval` does the string conversion and calls `evalin`). This method is discussed in this [MathWorks article](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html). The following code could be used:

```
T = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1];
syms u v;
eq1 = -T(13)*u^4 + (4*T(15) - 2*T(10) - T(11)*v)*u^3 + (3*T(13) - 3*T(6) ...
    + v*(3*T(14) -2*T(7)) - T(8)*v^2)*u^2 + (2*T(10) - 4*T(1) + v*(2*T(11) ...
    - 3*T(2)) + v^2*(2*T(12) - 2*T(3)) - T(4)*v^3)*u + v*(T(7) + T(8)*v ...
    + T(9)*v^2) + T(6);
eq2 = (T(14) - T(13)*v)*u^3 + u^2*(T(11) + (2*T(12) - 2*T(10))*v ...
    - T(11)*v^2) + u*(T(7) + v*(2*T(8) - 3*T(6) ) + v^2*(3*T(9) - 2*T(7)) ...
    - T(8)*v^3) + v*(2*T(3) - 4*T(1) + v*(3*T(4) - 3*T(2)) + v^2*(4*T(5) ...
    - 2*T(3)) - T(4)*v^3) + T(2);
allSolutions = feval(symengine, 'numeric::polysysroots',[eq1,eq2],'[u,v]');
```

The last argument still needed to be a string (or omitted) and adding `==0` to the equations also doesn't work, but the zero is implicit anyways.

For the second question, the result returned by [`numeric::polysysroots`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/numeric-polysysroots.html) is very inconvenient and not easy to work with. It's a set ([`DOM_SET`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom_set.html)) of matrices. I tried using [`coerce`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coerce.html) to convert the result to something else to no avail. I think you best bet it to convert the output to a string (using `char`) and parse the result. I do this for simpler output formats. I'm not sure if it will be helpful, but feel free to look at my [`sym2float`](https://github.com/horchler/SHCTools/blob/master/SHCTools/stoneholmes/private/sym2float.m) which just handles symbolic matrices (the `'matrix([[ ... ]])'` part go your output) using a few optimizations.

A last thing. Is there a reason your helper function includes superfluous parentheses? This seems sufficient

```
sT = @(x)num2str(T(x),17);
```

or

```
sT = @(x)sprintf('%.17g',T(x));
```

Note that `num2str` only converts to four decimal places by default. `int2str` (or `%d` should be used if `T(x)` is always an integer).

Comment: Hi, and thank you! I'll start by answering your last comment, the superfluous parentheses are needed since the elements in T are not necessarily positive so in my current version they are necessary, but maybe they're not with your suggestions. Regarding your other suggestions they look really good, but I can't test them properly until I'm back at work in a couple of days.

Comment: ps. I have too little reputation to upvote your answer but will do so as soon as I'm able. ds.

Comment: Please see my edit @horchler . I've implemented your suggestion and it works fine, except that sometimes it takes much longer time.

Comment: @Fija: Are you sure that `evalin` doesn't take equally long? The symbolic toolbox caches results so if you run the `feval` on a new equation first you may not get a fair comparison. You can try calling `clear all` and/or `clear classes`. There may be other things going on. In any case, you can expect `feval` to be a bit slower anyways for the reasons outlined in my answer.

Comment: No, I'm sure, did both `clear all` and `clear classes` between runs and `feval` takes approx 70 second and `evalin` approx 2 seconds. But I think your answer was good and this is a different problem so I'll accept your answer. =)

Comment: @Fija: What may be happening is that in some cases complicated analytic solutions may be returned at an intermediate step that are expensive to evaluate numerically. It's possible that how you specify the `evalin` code cases a numerical solution (symbolic class but entirely numeric) to be directly evaluated. The latter can be much faster if the formulas returned by `feval` are costly. You might see if you can use `vpa` on `T` or your equations.

Comment: I suppose that it could be the opposite as well and that in some case a numeric solution is evaluated that ends up being slow. The point is that the string that `feval` creates likely is different in terms of the numeric constants/parameters. The inclusion/exclusion of a decimal point (.0) can change how things are evaluated internally.